# How to change a shortcut for edit mode

Tags: shortcut, keymap

I am trying to change the shortcut of Box select to a simple Left mouse drag in both Object and Edit mode. Just to be sure, I changed every single possible shortcut to Box select in all the options that appear when I search Box select in keymap. It works for Object mode but not for Edit mode.
[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you want. I have two different _Box Select_ modes: the one where I simply drag with LMB, this mode switches selections i.e. if I select something, any old selection is gone. The second mode enabled by pressing B, in this mode every new selection is added to existing selections and dragging with scroll wheel subtracts selections. Now changing the keymap to _Left Mouse_ as you did only disabled selecting with LMB clicking, now I have to drag to select anything. Apart from that it's like before, not like the mode pressing B, but it's in _Edit Mode_ as well (like before).

Comment: All keymaps in Blender are organized by their context. Anything that is in edit mode is going to be under *3D View > Mesh* in this case this in particular it's in that section under *3D View Tool: Select Box*.

Comment: So it turns out that I had assigned the keymap correctly. HOWEVER, Left mouse button was assigned to Inset, which overruled my settings. My lesson learned from this, if I understood it wrong, is that you have to check if the keys are already assigned to somethings else.